# Batch file with simple FC command runs forever

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Why does my simple batch file run forever printing out the *only line* inside the **.bat** file over and over

My **fc.bat** file contents

```
FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
```

My desktop dir/

```
fc.bat
file1.txt
file2.txt!
```

[Here is a image of my cmd prompt after double clicking fc.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXFpy.png)

Output is

```
...
C:\Users\a\Desktop>FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
C:\Users\a\Desktop>FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
C:\Users\a\Desktop>FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
C:\Users\a\Desktop>FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
C:\Users\a\Desktop>FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
C:\Users\a\Desktop>FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
C:\Users\a\Desktop>FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
C:\Users\a\Desktop>FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
C:\Users\a\Desktop>FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
...
```

Comment: Change fc to fc.exe in your batch file or rename your batch file or fully qualify the path for fc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your batch file is in an infinite loop that calls itself over and over again.

```
FC "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
```

That is calling fc.bat, which is running the same command.  By default, batch files print out the line of code they run, which is why you are seeing that output.

Comment: "Matthew Frontino but why does it loop forever? I dont recall this happening othertimes...

Comment: It loops because you are executing that batch script over and over again.  FC.bat calls FC.bat calls FC.bat etc etc

Comment: Where am I telling FC.bat to call FC.bat?

Comment: The first two letters in your script

Comment: Ok, it seems that as I named my file **FC** that overrides the windows **FC*.exe command line tool to compare files, I now see that I am indeed calling fc.bat over and over again. I didnt know it takes precedence